# Firebase DatabaseException Can't convert object of type String

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting this strange error when trying to load a set of data into the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object
>   of type java.lang.String to type
>   com.magn.test.android.model.ProfilesData

Referring to this class:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class ProfilesData {

public String forename;
public String surname;
public String quote;
public String birth;
public String demise;
public String id;


public ProfilesData(){

}

public ProfilesData(String forename, String surname, String quote, String birth, String demise, String id){
    this.forename = forename;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.quote = quote;
    this.birth = birth;
    this.demise = demise;
    this.id = id;
}



public String getForename() {
    return forename;
}

public void setForename(String forename) {
    this.forename = forename;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public String getQuote() {
    return quote;
}

public void setQuote(String quote) {
    this.quote = quote;
}

public String getBirth() {
    return birth;
}

public void setBirth(String birth) {
    this.birth = birth;
}

public String getDemise() {
    return demise;
}

public void setDemise(String demise) {
    this.demise = demise;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

It would've been easier if I could narrow the issue down to a certain function/method, but the adapter does fetch the data as I print it out when it's done. It just doesn't end up in the layout, and the app crashes short after it is done.

Here's the Activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selection);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(this);

    //Initialize database
    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("profiles_info").child("1");


}


@Override
public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

}



@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ProfilesData, ProfilesViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ProfilesData, ProfilesViewHolder>(
            ProfilesData.class, R.layout.list_item, ProfilesViewHolder.class, database) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ProfilesViewHolder viewHolder, ProfilesData model, int position) {

            System.out.println("NAME ARE: " + model.getForename());

            viewHolder.setName(model.getForename() + " " + model.getSurname());
            viewHolder.setDates(model.getBirth() + " " + model.getDemise());


        }
    };

    // Scroll to bottom on new messages
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {

        }
    });

    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}







/**
 * ViewHolder to apply graphical changes when loading profiledata into adapter:
 */

public static class ProfilesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final TextView name_tv;
    private final TextView date_tv;

    public ProfilesViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        name_tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_name_tv);
        date_tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_dates_tv);
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        name_tv.setText(name);
    }

    public void setDates(String dates){
        date_tv.setText(dates);
    }

}
```

Comment: Solved here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552348/firebase-databaseexception-failed-to-convert-value-of-type-java-lang-long-to-st/45557421#45557421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough I simply was looking one "child" too far in my database:

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("profiles_info");
```

gave me the correct location and it could load everything correctly. Check your paths!

Comment: I have to wait a set of hours before I can do that.

Comment: "Check your paths" is perfect answer