# How do I get Firebase database value into UILabel text?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read a value from my Firebase database. I then want to change UILabel text to the database child value.  Seems pretty simple, but I cannot figure out why the value is reading blank.

Here is my Firebase JSON:

```
{
  "pilots" : {
    "HpPzn0XUqMgsKhUOpH75lHIhyFA3" : {
      "pilot" : "First Lastname",
      "weight" : 180
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the Firebase rules, just for testing at the moment:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "pilots": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true

    }
   }
 }
```

Finally the Swift 3 code, which is probably ugly as sin. First app after reading and online lessons.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class MainMenuViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var pilotUsername: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dateTime: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var aircraftLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var riskScoreInt: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

    ref.child("pilots").child(userID!).child("pilot").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        // Get user value
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let username = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""

        self.pilotUsername.text = username

        print(username)
        // ...
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }





}
}
```

I'm just using the example code from the Firebase documentation. There's a line of code (in the example) after

```
let username = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""
```

that  is :

```
let user = User.init(username: username)
```

but it gives me an error. "Use of unresolved identifier 'User'"

I don't think I need that line of code, since nothing like it is used in the examples and lessons that I've folowed.

Thank's in advance. This is my first time posting to Stack Overflow.

Comment: You need to create a `User` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import FirebaseDatabase

class User {

    // MARK: Properties

    var firstname: String
    var lastname: String
    var username: String { return "\(firstname)\(lastname)" }

    // MARK: Initializers

    init(firstname: String, lastname: String) {

        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
    }

    init?(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {

        guard
            let firstname = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "First").value as? String,
            let lastname = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Lastname").value as? String
        else { return nil }

        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
    }
}
```

Then

```
ref.child("pilots").child(userID!).child("pilot").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) in

    if let user = User(snapshot: snapshot) {

        self?.pilotUsername.text = user.username
    }

}) { (error) in

    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Okay I've created the user class, but your second block of code there confuses me a bit. the I'm getting a "Value 'user' was defined but never used" caution. The UILabel is still unchanged.  I've tried replacing my previous code, and leaving some, but I get build failed.

Comment: Yep, i forgot to add `self?.pilotUsername.text = user.username`

Comment: No more errors! The UILabel is still not changing though, so weird.  In the line `guard let username = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as? String else {` I've tried changing the forPath: to pilots and pilot, but that doesn't seem to do anything different.

Comment: Before you `User(snapshot: snapshot)`, print out the snapshot and show me the result

Comment: Here's the last bit **enabled
SIGN IN ATTEMPT
SIGN IN SUCCESS
Snap (pilot) First Lastname**  So it's getting the snapshot from the right spot in the database, but the UILabel isn't being changed...

Comment: Okay so that snapshot only seems to have `First` and `Lastname`, no `username`

Comment: I'm so sorry I believe I'm confusing you a bit.  I'm trying to get the UILabel to display "First Lastname" which is the value assigned to "pilot" in the database. So "First Lastname" could be "Bob Bobson" if it were changed to that, then UILabel should display that. `{
  "pilots" : {
    "HpPzn0XUqMgsKhUOpH75lHIhyFA3" : {
      "pilot" : "First Lastname",
      "weight" : 180
    }
  }
}`

Comment: I added and else statement after the if let, and that does update the UILabel text to "NO NAME". `if let user = User(snapshot: snapshot) {
                
                self?.pilotUsername.text = user.username
                
            } else {
                self?.pilotUsername.text = "NO NAME"
            } `

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED! I found this [POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443828/firebase-databaseexception-cant-convert-object-of-type-string) and decided to try removing the last .child(string) in the ref.child line. I'll posed working code.  I hope it's not a fluke.