# Android App crashes when Google maps connected to Firebase

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
    OnMapReadyCallback {

    public String Latvalue;
    public String Longvalue;
    public double val1;
    public double val2;
    DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference mLatRef = mRootRef.child("lat");
    DatabaseReference mLongRef = mRootRef.child("long");

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        mLatRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Latvalue = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                val1 = Double.parseDouble(Latvalue);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        mLongRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Longvalue = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                val2 = Double.parseDouble(Longvalue);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(val1 , val2);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Error:

```
 --------- beginning of crash
03-02 00:34:40.189 11487-11487/com.example.ashutosh.userappnew E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.ashutosh.userappnew, PID: 11487
 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzaF(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzb(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
     at com.example.ashutosh.userappnew.MapsActivity$1.onDataChange(MapsActivity.java:50)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZS(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5300)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
03-02 00:34:40.190 11487-11487/com.example.ashutosh.userappnew D/AppTracker: App Event: crash
03-02 00:34:40.291 11487-11487/com.example.ashutosh.userappnew I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11487 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552348/firebase-databaseexception-failed-to-convert-value-of-type-java-lang-long-to-st)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your stack trace:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String
```

You're trying to read a Long from the database as a String, and that's causing an exception.

```
Latvalue = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
val1 = Double.parseDouble(Latvalue);
...
Longvalue = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
val2 = Double.parseDouble(Longvalue);
```

Here you're reading `LatValue` and `LongValue` as Strings, so presumably they're actually Longs. I'm not sure why you would want to store or read them as Strings since you're immediately converting them to Double anyway. Just cast the default value to double:

```
val1 = (double)dataSnapshot.getValue();
...
val2 = (double)dataSnapshot.getValue();
```

See the Firebase docs on [reading and writing data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_and_write_data).

Comment: Thanks Travis! I did the changes you suggested and now the app doesn't crash. But it is still unable to retrieve the values .