# DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

## AskFirebase

I recieved the following error:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzaF(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzb(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzb(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg$zza.zze(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg$zza.zzaH(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zze(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzb(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
  at in.thegeekybaniya.q_time.EventFrag$2.onDataChange(EventFrag.java:81)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZS(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

At:

```
 mChild.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        public static final String TAG = "Members";

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot child :
                    dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                eventArrayList.add(child.getValue(Event.class));

                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + eventArrayList.toString());

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

My database looks like this:

[image]

Here is my Event class:

```
package in.thegeekybaniya.q_time;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Event {
    int likes, dislikes;
    String name, key;
    ArrayList<String> likeList, dislikeList;
    int report;


    public Event(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.likes = 0;
        this.dislikes = 0;
        this.report = 0;


        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add("abcd");

        this.likeList = arrayList;
        this.dislikeList = arrayList;
    }

    public Event(int likes, int dislikes, String name, String key, ArrayList<String> likeList, ArrayList<String> dislikeList, int report) {
        this.likes = likes;
        this.dislikes = dislikes;
        this.name = name;
        this.key = key;
        this.likeList = likeList;
        this.dislikeList = dislikeList;
        this.report = report;
    }

    public Event() {

    }

    public void dislikePressedFirst() {
        this.dislikes += 1;
    }

    public void likePressed() {
        this.likes += 1;
        this.dislikes -= 1;
    }

    public void dislikePressed() {
        this.dislikes += 1;
        this.likes -= 1;
    }

    public void likePressedFirst() {
        this.likes += 1;
    }

    public int getLikes() {
        return likes;
    }

    public void setLikes(int likes) {
        this.likes = likes;
    }

    public int getDislikes() {
        return dislikes;
    }

    public void setDislikes(int dislikes) {
        this.dislikes = dislikes;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getLikeList() {
        return likeList;
    }

    public void setLikeList(ArrayList<String> likeList) {
        this.likeList = likeList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Event{" +
                "likes=" + likes +
                ", dislikes=" + dislikes +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", key='" + key + '\'' +
                ", likeList=" + likeList +
                ", dislikeList=" + dislikeList +
                ", report=" + report +
                '}';
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getDislikeList() {
        return dislikeList;
    }

    public void setDislikeList(ArrayList<String> dislikeList) {
        this.dislikeList = dislikeList;
    }

    public int getReport() {
        return report;
    }

    public void setReport(int report) {
        this.report = report;
    }
}
```

Here is a snapshot:

[image]

Please help.

Sorry Earlier I had pasted code from the wrong Fragment. Please Forgive.

One of my friends suggested that FireBase has a Hard TIme dealing with Integers, and It would be a good idea o convert Integers to String and Parse them every time.

Update(19/5/17)- Everything Works if i Remove the int report from class(and edit getters setters and related functionality), this is some serious combination of data members.

Comment: It seems there is a number where a String is expected. Could it be that somewhere in your database there is some incorrect data where an entry has a number with no "" marks where it shouldn't be?

Comment: The Attached picture is of my database as of now. And it is still giving me errors.

Comment: Replace int to Long in your PoJo class because firebase return Long value.

Comment: @ashish already tried, thank you though

Comment: Solved here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552348/firebase-databaseexception-failed-to-convert-value-of-type-java-lang-long-to-st/45557421#45557421