# Android, get value from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, location

I need to add markers from all users on my map. I'm saving all coordinates in my firebase

My database looks like:

[image]

So, when I want to get values: lat, lng from database(I do it in onMapReady method):

```
int allUsers = 100;
    while(allUsers >= 0) {
        double latAll = Double.parseDouble(users.child("lat").toString());
        double lngAll = Double.parseDouble(users.child("lng").toString());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latAll, lngAll)));
    }
```

I get an error

Here i'm saving values ito my database:

```
GPSTracker gpstracker = new GPSTracker(mContext, SearchActivity.this);
                double locationLng = gpstracker.getLongitude();
                double locationLat = gpstracker.getLatitude();

                databaseReference.child("lng").setValue(locationLng);
                databaseReference.child("lat").setValue(locationLat);
```

here is my error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    Process: kz.mul.livemeet_finalversion, PID: 24598
>                                                    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "https://livemeetfinalversion.firebaseio.com/ekeLu1W_1RU%3AAPA91bFt2knzJYknyWLpuFb1Wm1nxl0TkM-bWdkNrjaoPUmv5JP_hm6b64Hx3m3X805A3QR8paMAOABJN6DZcb99z_EfwGwadN1dUN6ngtqTbGwxD6iMLlP7IW6RvEzg9UTW7HQKHyT0/lat"
>                                                        at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1306)
>                                                        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:547)
>                                                        at kz.mul.livemeet_finalversion.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:118)
>                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzt$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
>                                                        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
>                                                        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bw.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82)
>                                                        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bf.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:1805)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: What is your parent child name ?

Comment: please show us your error log..

Comment: Solved here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552348/firebase-databaseexception-failed-to-convert-value-of-type-java-lang-long-to-st/45557421#45557421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1) Make a PoJo.class which contains all the keys that are in database in you case like age,lat,lng etc.

Step 2) Now call this method for getting all the data.like below

```
    public void getAllUsersFromFirebase() { 
    DatabaseReference UserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Parent_child");
    UserRef.keepSynced(true);
    UserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterator<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshots = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
            List<PoJo> fcmUsers = new ArrayList<>();
            while (dataSnapshots.hasNext()) {
                DataSnapshot dataSnapshotChild = dataSnapshots.next();
                PoJo fcmUser = dataSnapshotChild.getValue(PoJo.class);
                fcmUsers.add(fcmUser);

            } 

            // Check your arraylist size and pass to list view like 
            if(fcmUsers.size()>0)
            { 
                fcmUsers arraylist pass to your Map activity.

            }else 
            { 
                // Display dialog for there is no user available. 
            } 

        } 

        @Override 
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // for handling database error           
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: It's not clear for me, where you write pass to your Map activity