# Retrieve data from nested saved data in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this structure:

[image]

And I need to get the data from "OnlineClients". My attempt:

```
currentDriverId = mFireBaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
mDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Driver").child(currentDriverId).child("OnlineClients");
final ArrayList<Student> users = new ArrayList<>();
        ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Student student  = data.getValue(Student.class);
                    users.add(student);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Getting Post failed, log a message
            }
        };
        mDataBase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(postListener);
```

with error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert
>   value of type java.lang.Long to String

Student.Class:

```
public class Student {
    private String FirstName;
    private String LastName;
    private String StudentSchool;
    private String StudentState;
    private String StudentStreet;
    private String StudentStreetNumber;


    public Student(){
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        FirstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getStudentSchool() {
        return StudentSchool;
    }

    public void setStudentSchool(String studentSchool) {
        StudentSchool = studentSchool;
    }

    public String getStudentState() {
        return StudentState;
    }

    public void setStudentState(String studentState) {
        StudentState = studentState;
    }

    public String getStudentStreet() {
        return StudentStreet;
    }

    public void setStudentStreet(String studentStreet) {
        StudentStreet = studentStreet;
    }

    public String getStudentStreetNumber() {
        return StudentStreetNumber;
    }

    public void setStudentStreetNumber(String studentStreetNumber) {
        StudentStreetNumber = studentStreetNumber;
    }
}
```

Already tried: [how to retrieve all the data within nested firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537968/how-to-retrieve-all-the-data-within-nested-firebase-database) and similar without success.

Note: I only need to retrieve "OnlineClients" from current logged user (that's why I'm just using currentDriverId).

Comment: Please add the content of your `Student` class.

Comment: @AlexMamo added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code lies in the fact that your `StudentStreetNumber` field is declared in your `Student` class of type `String` while in your database is a number (long). To solve this, simply change the type of your property to `long`:

```
private long StudentStreetNumber;
```

Another problem in your code are the getters. To solve this problem too, please see my answer from the following post:

- [Firebase Android ListView not being displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069574/firebase-android-listview-not-being-displayed)

Comment: That was it! Actually I had inconsistencies (in one class it was declared as int and probably then casted to long and in the other as String). It was not necessary to change my current code, but to fix these inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      Student student  = data.getValue(Student.class);
      users.add(student);
   }

}
```

into this:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  Student student  = dataSnapshot.getValue(Student.class);
  users.add(student);
}
```

Remove the for loop because when you are looping, you are retrieving the values as `String`. Also make sure when you use `setValue()` you are adding an object of Type `Student` as an argument.

Another way to retrieve the values is to do the following:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
 for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    String firstName = data.child("FirstName").getValue(String.class);
    String lastName  = data.child("LastName").getValue(String.class);
     }
}
```